# Contact Form gives me a 404 page in MAGENTO

Tags: magento

I’m new I magento and it is giving me a lot of headaches. I can’t get the contact form to work, this is the URL 
http://blokeundees.com.au/index.php/contact

My code on the contact us block is

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="http://blokeundees.com.au/index.php/contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

also tried

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

But with this one is sending to a The requested URL `/contacts/index/post/` was not found on this server page

My configuration is:

```
Enable Contact Us -> Yes
```

I don’t know what to do and can’t find a solution

Hope somebody can help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the contact form is enabled in the backend:

```
System -> Configuration -> General -> Contacts -> Contact Us -> Enable
```

Answer (score 0):

Dude, I just clicked on the above link and filled the contact form and submitted a comment also. But you are saying it gives 404 error. Can you please clear your browser cache(by ctrl+F5) and reload the page once again??

Comment: So what is the mistake that you did earlier?

Comment: I was using this code {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}, which is not working.

Now I used {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="http://blokeundees.com.au/index.php/contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}, which works fine.

Comment: But you should not directly mention the URL in the the form action. If the url gets change, then it will become problem for you. AS of now, it is ok. But there might be another way to do this.

Comment: yes exactly, but for now i dont have any other way to do this and even i dont have much time because my client got irritated. If you have any  other way then please help me.

Comment: From which page you are calling the above block. Is the call is from static blocks or template files?

Comment: I just copied this {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/form.phtml"}} to one of my cms pages and there it shows the form as required submitted form as well. And also I tried with this also {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="magento/index.php/contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/form.phtml"}} Now it loads the form and if I try to submit comment, then it gives the 404 error.

Comment: Just flush your cache and try placing this in ur CMS Page {{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="/contacts/index/post" template="contacts/form.phtml"}} and try once again...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. My solution is as follows:

My domain root URL: `www.example.com/online/`

The page URL with the contact form: `www.example.com/online/contact-us`

If you want the post action working, you have to make sure the path for `contacts/index/post` is under your domain root path. In my case, I use this one

```
{{block type="core/template" name="contactForm" form_action="../contacts/index/post/" template="contacts/form.phtml"}}
```

Once I click the sumbit button, the url goes to `www.example.com/online/contacts/index/post/` and the page shows that "Your inquiry was submitted and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thank you for contacting us."

Answer (score 0):

In your template

> /template/contacts/form.phtml

change form action from **contacts/index/post/** to **contacts/index/save/**

Comment: This can be a comment but not an answer. Read the rules, please.

Comment: This is the solution! @dpap

Comment: If you think this is the solution then try to edit your answer to be more clear and readable.