# Custom contact form gives me 404 error

Tags: magento, http-status-code-404, contact-form

I've created a custom contact form for each magento product, I've set up all the files and inserted this code inside a Magento static block:

```
{{block type="core/template" form_action="/PersonalizzazioniEmail/index/post/"  template="catalog/product/view/form-personalizzazione.phtml"}}
```

Here's the form-personalizzazione.phtml

```html
<?php $productId=$this->getRequest()->getParams();   
$model = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');  
$_product = $model->load($productId["id"]);   
?>

<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->toHtml() ?></div>
<div class="page-title">
 <h1><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Us') ?></h1>
</div>
<form action="<?php echo $this->getFormAction(); ?>" id="contactForm" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="product" name="product" value="<?php echo $_product->getName() ?>" /> 
 <div class="fieldset">
  <h2 class="legend"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Contact Information') ?></h2>
  <ul class="form-list">
   <li class="fields">
    <div class="field">
     <label for="name" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name') ?></label>
     <div class="input-box">
      <input name="name" id="name" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Name')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry" type="text" />
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
     <label for="email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email') ?></label>
     <div class="input-box">
      <input name="email" id="email" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Email')) ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->helper('contacts')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-email" type="text" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <label for="telephone"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
     <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Telephone')) ?>" value="" class="input-text" type="text" />
    </div>
   </li>
   <li class="wide">
    <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
     <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment')) ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 
 <div class="fieldset privacy">
  <ul class="form-list">
   <?php if (Mage::helper('privacy')->isPrivacyEnabled()): ?>
   <li>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('privacy.include.contacts'); ?>
   </li>
   <?php endif;?>
  </ul>
 </div>
 
 <div class="buttons-set">
  <p class="required"><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
  <input type="text" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" style="display:none !important;" />
  <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit')) ?>" class="button"><span><span><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
 </div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 var contactForm = new VarienForm('contactForm', true);
//]]>
</script>
```

But I get a 404 error when I submit the form, what could be the reason?
Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642846/contact-form-gives-me-a-404-page-in-magento) question maybe?

Comment: Already tried with ../ at the beginning and I've checked that the contact form is enabled

Comment: the leading `/` means that your form action will directly redirect to `www.domain.com/xxx` which in your case is : `www.domain.com/PersonalizzazioniEmail/index/post/`

Comment: I'm trying also on my main website but I keep getting 404 http://www.arredomobilionline.com/PersonalizzazioniEmail/index/post/

Comment: also share code of form-personalizzazione.phtml mailny form tag.

Comment: I've added the code on top

Answer (score 1):

**Create a Custom Contact Form in Magento,Kindly visit below URLs.**

> http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-email/magento-custom-email-contact-form-with-notification-system/
>
> http://ignaciogondra.com/2015/08/24/how-to-create-a-custom-contact-form-in-magento/
>
> If you don't want to use custom code,You can use this paid extension.
>
> https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-contact-forms.html
>
> You can also use this Product Question,It's might be fulfilled your requirement. This is free extension.
>
> https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-question-1.html
>
> Hope It's helpful for you.

Comment: Answers sharing ONLY links to external websites are not really helpful. Soon or late those links would disappear and your answer will be of no value then :)